# Is my heapsort project's time complexity N * log(N)?

Tags: c, heapsort

I tried to write "heap sort". So I made some quite a simple C language project. But I wondered why my code's time complexity is O(N * log(N))?
I compared the code of others and it seems quite similar, so I brought it up here to get some advice.

Below is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int *intarray;
int size;
void heapify(int n, int max);
void heap_sort(int n);

//시간복잡도는 O(N * log N)
int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &size);
    intarray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(4 * (size + 1)));
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &*(intarray + i));
    //입력끝
    heap_sort(size);
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        printf(" [ %d ] ", intarray[i]);
    printf("프로그램종료");
    return 0;
}

void heapify(int n, int max)
{
    if (n > max)
        return;
    heapify(n * 2, max);
    heapify((n * 2) + 1, max);
    if (intarray[n] > intarray[n / 2] && n != 1) {
        int temp = intarray[n];
        intarray[n] = intarray[n / 2];
        intarray[n / 2] = temp;
    }
}

void heap_sort(int n)
{
    if (n < 1)
        return;
    heapify(1, n);
    int temp;
    temp = intarray[1];
    intarray[1] = intarray[n];
    intarray[n] = temp;
    heap_sort(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: `intarray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(4 * (size+1)));` is invalid. That's just `malloc(sizeof(int))` - one `int`.

Comment: I amended it! thx! incidentally, How about time's complexity?? KamilCuk.

Comment: Because you're recursively calling `heapify` with less and less elements.

Comment: And the number of elements decreases geometrically (not arithmetically) at each recursion. `heapify` alone has time complexity O(log(N)) but `heapify` is called N times by `heap_sort` (with linearly decreasing N) so the overall time complexity for `heap_sort` is O(N * log(N)).

Comment: Were you expecting the time complexity of heapsort to be something other than O(n log(n))?

Comment: Thank you for comment, I know the heapsort's time complexity is O(n log(N) but, I only saw a theory of heap sorting process before I actually embodied it by C Language. So, I wondered that even my code works properly,  does my code's time complexity also work as a  (O(N * log(N))?  or did I put unnecessary process in the code?